# Pass by the front of the house(phrasal verb)

Tags: word-choice, phrasal-verbs

Let's say there is a 'haunted house' in a town and its neighbors are terrified by it every time they pass by, and you say it like this:

> The haunted house's neighbors are terrified every time these people **pass by** the front of the house.

Is it **pass by the front** of the house or **pass by in front** of the house?

Comment: Not so much difference, and both are OK. "pass by the front" focuses on the front of the house, while "pass by in front" focuses on the path.

Comment: Yes you can pass by *in front, the front, the back, the sides etc*. But houses don't really have neighbours, people do (although you can speak about **neighbouring houses**.. And you would say **they pass by** rather than *these people pass by*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not much difference. But I would just say "pass by the house". The fact it is to the front of the house is understood from what we know about houses. You could even shorten it to "pass it by" or just "pass by." since "the house" is understood from the context. Note that "pass by" is a separable phrasal verb.

> There is a haunted house in our town and people are terrified every time they pass [it] by.

I've dealt with the issues that Ronald Sole notes in a comment.